# Eclipse giving uninitialized compile time error when initialization occurs inside try/catch

Tags: java, initialization, try-catch, ioexception

I'm having trouble with a block of code that is telling me that a variable is not initialized even though I initialized it within a try/catch block.

The code I have is:

```
public String doSomething(String input1, String input2) {
    CustomizedObject myobject = new CustomizedObject();
    try {
        Output out = (Output) myobject.getOutput();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return out.doSomethingString(input1, input2);
}
```

However, it is saying that I need to create a local variable "out."

The code for my CustomizedObject is below:

```
public class CustomizedObject {

   private String attribute;

   public CustomizedObject() {
        attribute = "awesome";
   }

   public String getOutput() throws IOException {
       //.....code doing some stuff......
       return attribute;
   }
}
```

Comment: Your error-message doesn't match your code. The problem with your code is that `out` is *undeclared* (i.e., out-of-scope) outside of the `try`-block, but the "initialized" error-message means that it is declared but may not have a value. You should always post code that demonstrates the actual problem you're having, and you should always post the actual compile error-message, verbatim (if only so that other people with this problem can find the answer when they Google the error-message).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't initialize the `Output out` inside the try/catch block. Try the following:

```
public String doSomething(String input1, String input2) {
    CustomizedObject myobject = new CustomizedObject();
    Output out = null;
    try {
        out = (Output) myobject.getOutput();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return out.doSomethingString(input1, input2);
}
```

Note, that the above code will throw a `NullPointerException` if the `IOException` is thrown; so you probably don't want to `out.doSomething` if `out == null`.

Answer (score 2):

If you code throws an exception at `Output out = (Output) myobject.getOutput();`, it will not be able to execute the return statement. You should move your existing `return` to inside of the try, and have a separate return if the try returns a catch.

```
public String doSomething(String input1, String input2) {
    CustomizedObject myobject = new CustomizedObject();
    try {
        Output out = (Output) myobject.getOutput();
        return out.doSomethingString(input1, input2);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        return "Something went wrong";
    }
}
```